# How Can I Make This Debounce Script Work? Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debouncing

This is my script, when I click the debounce works at first, but after the wait you can just spam click and shoot many bullets at once. How can I fix this? I am a beginner so any help will be nice :) I had to get rid of some because stack overflow wasn't happy

```
using Photon.Pun;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SingleShotGun : Gun
{
    [SerializeField] Camera cam;

    PhotonView PV;

    public bool debounce = false;

    public float debounce2;

    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public AudioClip audioClip;

    private float timeStarted;
    private float audioTime;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (PV.IsMine)
        {
            audioSource.clip = audioClip;
            float timeStarted = (float)PhotonNetwork.Time;
            audioTime = 0;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (PV.IsMine)
        {
            float audioTime = (float)PhotonNetwork.Time - timeStarted;
        }
        else
        {
            audioSource.time = audioTime;
        }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        PV = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    }

    public override void Use()
    {
        if (debounce)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Deb());
            return;
        }
        if (PV.IsMine)
        {
            audioSource.clip = audioClip;
            float timeStarted = (float)PhotonNetwork.Time;
        }
        debounce = true;
        Shoot();
    }

    private IEnumerator Deb()
    {
        Debug.Log("Debouncing");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(debounce2);
        debounce = false;
    }
}
```

I Tried to make a debounce script for unity3d, but it didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first note: in

```
float audioTime = (float)PhotonNetwork.Time - timeStarted;
```

you are creating a new local variable => the class field `audioTime` is not assigned in that case

same also for all occurrences of

```
float timeStarted = (float)PhotonNetwork.Time;
```

you want to remove the `float` in all three places in order to rather assign your class fields instead of over shadowing them with same named local variables, otherwise they will always have the default value `0`.

---

Then within `Use` you are starting multiple concurrent routines that will all finish eventually and reset your `debounce` in unexpected moments. You probably rather want to wrap it in order to start only a single routine like

```
if(!debounce)
{
    debounce = true;
    Shoot();
    StartCoroutine(Deb()):
}
```

Also again in general I would expect the entire `Use` should be wrapped in / start with

```
if (!PV.IsMine) return;
```

as it looks and sounds like none of those things should happen at all if this is not your gun ;)

And after setting

```
audioSource.clip = audioClip;
```

you also need to

```
audioSource.Play();
```